# Remove all characters from string except for whitelisted phrases, and remove empty elements

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I need to use `preg_replace()` in php to remove all string words except the ones inside the `$querys` array.

Additionally, elements that do not contain a whitelisted word should be removed.

In the string:

```
$text = [
   0 => 'Tomada de Preços nº 003/2019',
   1 => 'PREGÃO ELETRÔNICO Nº 001/2019',
   2 => 'Processo Nº 011/2019',
   3 => 'Aviso de Licitação CONCORRÊNCIA PÚBLICA Nº 3/2019',
);

$querys = [
    'CONCORRÊNCIA',
    'Tomada de Preços',
    'PREGÃO ELETRÔNICO'
];

$result = [
   0 => 'Tomada de Preços',
   1 => 'PREGÃO ELETRÔNICO',
   3 => 'CONCORRÊNCIA PÚBLICA',
];
```

Comment: `PÚBLICA` is not in `$querys` but is in `$Result`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My guess is that maybe some simple expression such as the following might be OK to look into:

```
\b(?:CONCORRÊNCIA|Tomada de Preços|PREGÃO ELETRÔNICO)\b
```

#### Test

```
$re = '/\b(?:CONCORRÊNCIA|Tomada de Preços|PREGÃO ELETRÔNICO)\b/s';

$arr = array(
    '0' => 'Tomada de Preços nº 003/2019',
    '1' => 'PREGÃO ELETRÔNICO Nº 001/2019',
    '2' => 'Processo Nº 011/2019',
    '3' => 'Aviso de Licitação CONCORRÊNCIA PÚBLICA Nº 3/2019',
);

$result = array();

foreach ($arr as $value) {
    if (preg_match_all($re, $value, $matches[0])) {
        preg_match($re, $value, $matches);
        array_push($result, $matches[0]);
    }
}

var_dump($result);
```

#### Output

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(17) "Tomada de Preços"
  [1]=>
  string(19) "PREGÃO ELETRÔNICO"
  [2]=>
  string(13) "CONCORRÊNCIA"
}
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/lWKxp2/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/lWKxp2/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

Answer (score 0):

Most directly, this is a great use case for `preg_filter()` assuming that you only expect to find one match per element. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ZHATQ))

```
var_export(
    preg_filter('/.*\b(' . implode('|', $whitelist) . ')\b.*/', '$1', $inputs)
);
```

---

A more verbose solution would be looped `preg_match()` or `preg_replace()` calls with conditional pushing into the result array.

If your inputs might contain characters with special meaning within regex, you will need to call `preg_quote()` on those values before imploding.

The `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` trick effectively avoids the removal of the whitelisted substrings.  Everything else gets chewed up and spat out via `.*?` matching.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/OCftv))

```
$whitelist = [
    'CONCORRÊNCIA PÚBLICA',
    'Tomada de Preços',
    'PREGÃO ELETRÔNICO'
];

$pattern = '/\b(?:' . implode('|', $whitelist) . ')\b(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|.*?/';

foreach ($inputs as $i => $input) {
    $inputs[$i] = preg_replace($pattern, '', $input);
    if (!$inputs[$i]) {
        unset($inputs[$i]);
    }
}
var_export($inputs);
```

Or: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/YHZG0))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($inputs as $i => $input) {
    if (preg_match('/\b(?:' . implode('|', $whitelist) . ')\b/', $input, $m)) {
        $result[$i] = $m[0];
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'Tomada de Preços',
  1 => 'PREGÃO ELETRÔNICO',
  3 => 'CONCORRÊNCIA PÚBLICA',
)
```